# Redirect already logged in users in Sails

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, sails.js, passport.js

I have a Sails.js application redirecting users to `/dashbaord` after login through the `/login` page.

What I would like is to automatically redirect to `/dashboard` users that are already logged in and try to access any page, be it the homepage or any other.

How can I achieve that in Sails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved what I wanted thanks to Ron Smith and Bonanza.

For some reason `req.session.authenticated` was `undefined` when calling the policy from a route, so here is my `api/policies/forceDashboard.js`:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user) {
        return res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }

    return next();
};
```

Then, as Bonanza advised me to, I added the policy to the routes in `config/routes.js`:

```
'/': [
    { policy: 'forceDashboard' },
    { view: 'homepage' }
],

'get /login': [
    { policy: 'forceDashboard' },
    { view: 'login' }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of without more info would be to create a policy, and then apply this policy to all the relevant controllers and actions.  One possible example:

```
// api/policies/forceDashboard.js
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.authenticated) {
    return res.redirect('/dashboard');
  }

  return next();
};

// config/policies.js

module.exports.policies = {
  '*': 'forceDashboard',

  'DashboardController': {
    'find': 'sessionAuth',
    '*': 'forceDashboard'
  }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work... In fact I already have an 'isAuthenticated' policy that redirects the users to `/login` if they are not authenticated and to `/dashboard` if they are.
And I have the following policy : '*': [ 'isAuthenticated'], but it doesn't seem to get triggered when loading a static page like `/` or `/login`.

Comment: @Bertrand31 But you have controller for those pages ```/``` and ```/login``` ? If yes just add those policies to them and it will be fine.

Comment: I do not have a controller for `/`, and `/login`'s controller is only triggered when POSTing data. Since they are both static pages they don't need controllers.
Maybe I need to add controllers to theese pages? Isn't there a cleaner way?

Comment: So you have router for them. You can add policy in router. [Sails custom routes](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes)